# Cache tableView Cell data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, custom-cell

In my application I'm downloading some images using the URL and put them in the `cell.imageView[indexPath.row]` (it's a custom cell with an imageView inside).
I can see two cells at a time and I noticed that the method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CustomCell {
}
```

It's called every time the cell will be displayed. So my app continue to download the image from the server and the app result very slow.

I would like to know if it's possible to cache the data of the cells I already saw, so I don't need to re-download the image if I scroll up in my tableView! Code speaking I would like to call the `func` written above only if I scroll down the table and not for the cells I already saw.

Answer (score 1):

You can but it takes a fair bit of work so the nice people at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) make a library to download / cache / fetch / manage your image URLs just swap your image getting code with this category for `UIImageview`, this gives `UIImageView.sd_` methods.

Also with cells implement `prepareForReuse()` and cancel the fetch with `sd_cancel`

Answer (score 1):

Do not reinvent the wheel!
Take a look at NSCache, it works like a mutable dictionary but it thread safe.

> NSCache objects differ from other mutable collections in a few ways:
>
> The NSCache class incorporates various auto-removal policies, which
>   ensure that it does not use too much of the system’s memory. The
>   system automatically carries out these policies if memory is needed by
>   other applications. When invoked, these policies remove some items
>   from the cache, minimizing its memory footprint.
>
> You can add, remove, and query items in the cache from different
>   threads without having to lock the cache yourself.
>
> Unlike an NSMutableDictionary object, a cache does not copy the key
>   objects that are put into it.
>
> These features are necessary for the NSCache class, as the cache may
>   decide to automatically mutate itself asynchronously behind the scenes
>   if it is called to free up memory.

You can key your images using their URL and them as a value.
[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/). 
[NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nscache/) post.