# how to use Cache directory for image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cache-control

I am showing picture in tableview . I want that if image is already downloaded then do not download again .how to implement this scenario using  cache directory.

Comment: have you tried anything ?

Comment: i am not able to find a good solution. i got link can you see this is use full.http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tutorials/13315-image-caching-tutorial.html

Comment: things you have tried , you should add to your question. that shows what you have researched and is usually commended with upvotes for asking a well researched question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cache tableView Cell data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646968/cache-tableview-cell-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at NSCache, it works like a mutable dictionary but it thread safe.

> NSCache objects differ from other mutable collections in a few ways:
>
> The NSCache class incorporates various auto-removal policies, which
>   ensure that it does not use too much of the system’s memory. The
>   system automatically carries out these policies if memory is needed by
>   other applications. When invoked, these policies remove some items
>   from the cache, minimizing its memory footprint.
>
> You can add, remove, and query items in the cache from different
>   threads without having to lock the cache yourself.
>
> Unlike an NSMutableDictionary object, a cache does not copy the key
>   objects that are put into it.
>
> These features are necessary for the NSCache class, as the cache may
>   decide to automatically mutate itself asynchronously behind the scenes
>   if it is called to free up memory.

You can key your images using their URL and the image itself as a value.
[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/). 
[NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nscache/) post.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) for that. this is great library. download from given github link and just drag and drop `SDWEbImage` folder in your project.

Then import `UIImageView+WebCache.h` in your class like

```
#import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
```

then in your `cellforRowAtIndexpath`

```
 [cell.myImageView sd_setImageWithURL:finalImageUrl];
```

you can read instructions on github page for more details about this library

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

[Use this for Image download in cache [MNMRemoteimageview]](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mnmremoteimageview)